# Why do the renders come out different on two machines?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

For context - I am trying to spin up machines in the cloud (Digital Ocean) to speed up rendering compared to my underpowered laptop. Also - using Blender since yesterday.

On both machines Blender is version 2.92.0.

However the output generated by this command on the exact same file:

```
blender-2.92.0-linux64/blender -b pet_shop.blend -x 1 -E CYCLES -o  //pet_shop -f 1
```

looked different on the two machines. On my laptop it looked like this:

[image: local machine render]

and on the Digital Ocean machine it looked like this:

[image: digital ocean render]

Until I copied the preferences from my local machine to the remote one

What are the preference settings that result in this?

Comment: it looks like you've lost the image you use as world image (pink means image missing)

Comment: @brockmann - partially: that and finding out that a plugin I used locally includes a background file. I would say the answer is: in order to ensure the exact same outcome you have to have the exact same configuration on both machines - not only the same install. You probably are missing a file in the config of your remote - pink means image is missing. Or is it too obvious?